# How to fix a DateTime update issue in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: sqlite, xamarin.forms, sqlite-net

I am using xamarin forms. I have some issue on datetime field in SQLite update.

The following Table in I am using:

```
public class DataTable
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int WorkOrderId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<DateTime> TargetDateTime { get; set; }
}
```

For DatePicker.Date, I am using DatePicker in design with the selection of any date:

```
DateChange dateChange=new DateChange();
dateChange.WorkOrderId=1;
dateChange.RescheduleDate=DatePicker.Date;
AddMwoReschedule(dateChange);
```

This is the update statement, I am using:

```
public List<EngMwoReschedulingTxn> AddMwoReschedule(DateChange dateChange)
{
    DateTime dt = new DateTime();
    dt = dateChange.RescheduleDate;
    conn.Query<DataTable>("update DataTable set TargetDateTime='" + dt + "' where WorkOrderId='"+engMwoReschedulingTxn.WorkOrderId+"'");
}
```

**Result:**

The Updated **TargetDateTime** for table **DataTable** comes like below:
01-01-0001 00:00:00

Can anyone help me solve this issue?

Comment: Can you provide, which library are you using for SQLite? Maybe SQL-net? Or something else?

Comment: I am using SQLite.Net-PCL.

Comment: Have you checked what dateChange.RescheduleDate; is return in dt variable?

Comment: dt returns like '03-08-2018 00:00:00'

Comment: I had similar problems with DateTime field in SQLite Query So I tried Writing Query using LINQ which accpeted DateTime as expected. I used same  NuGet Package for SQLite

Comment: hi mohammad, can you give me sample?

Comment: hi mohammed, this is working fine using LinQ code.
I am using the query like this:
conn.Query<DataTable>("update DataTable set TargetDateTime='" + dt.Ticks + "' where WorkOrderId='"+engMwoReschedulingTxn.WorkOrderId+"'");

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is working fine using LinQ code. I am using the query like this: conn.Query("update DataTable set TargetDateTime='" + dt.Ticks + "' where WorkOrderId='"+engMwoReschedulingTxn.WorkOrderId+"'");